# php opendir(different domain folder) - Is this possible to achieve?

Tags: php

I'm trying to manage away of knowing witch images are inside the predefined pics folder on my domains.

I'm trying with opendir, but it always fails, even if I'm sure my folder is there, so I guess the problem is the crossdomain thing.

Having ftp credentials, is there a way of let php know that I can indeed read the content of my folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must the [`ftp_`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) series of functions to achieve what you're describing.

For example:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect($server);
ftp_login($ftp, $username, $password);
ftp_chdir($ftp, $images_dir);

$files = ftp_nlist($ftp); // Array of files in the images folder
```